# How to conditionally return either one field or another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Customer` table. This table consists of fields `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `CompanyName`. The business logic is that if there is any value at all for `CompanyName`, a query should return `CompanyName`, otherwise, if `CompanyName` is either `NULL` or empty, it should return a combination of `FirstName` and `LastName`.

All I have as of now is...

```
select ID, (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as EntityName from Customer
```

or

```
select ID, (CompanyName) as EntityName from Customer
```

How do I write such a `select` query to return one or the other in `EntityName`, based on whether a value exists for `CompanyName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select ID
      ,EntityName = case when Isnull(CompanyName,'') <>'' then CompanyName  else FirstName + ' ' + LastName end
 From Customer
```

Answer (score 4):

You would use `COALESCE()`:

```
select ID, COALESCE(CompanyName, FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as EntityName
from Customer;
```

This assumes that a `NULL` value indicates that `CompanyName` is missing.  Otherwise, you would use a `CASE` with the appropriate logic.

Comment: This does work if `CompanyName` is `NULL`, but as you say, if it's an empty string, it does not. The database I'm working with can have empty values. Thus a `CASE` statement is needed.

Answer (score 1):

COALESCE() will not work for empty string . So you can depend on the '**case**' statement and also put a **null** check on the first name and last name columns in order to keep the result valid.
if any of these columns contains a null value, then the entire result will be null.

```
Select ID
      ,EntityName = CASE WHEN ISNULL(CompanyName,'') ='' 
                         THEN ISNULL(FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(LastName,'')  --if company name is null or empty will take the combination of firstname and last name
                    ELSE CompanyName END 
From Customer
```